# Javascript nested class

Tags: javascript

How do I define nested class in Java Script.

Here is the code snippet I have:

```
objA = new TestA();

function TestB ()
{
   this.testPrint = function ()
  {
     print ( " Inside testPrint " );
  }
}

function TestA ()
{
   var myObjB = new TestB();
}
```

Now I am trying to access testPrint using objA

```
objA.myObjB.testPrint();
```

But its giving error "objA has no properties"

How can I access testB method using objA handler?

Answer (score 11):

If you want the prototype definition of the inner nested classes to be not accessible from outside the outer class, as well as a cleaner OO implementation, take a look at this.

```
var BobsGarage = BobsGarage || {}; // namespace

/**
 * BobsGarage.Car
 * @constructor
 * @returns {BobsGarage.Car}
 */
BobsGarage.Car = function() {

    /**
     * Engine
     * @constructor
     * @returns {Engine}
     */
    var Engine = function() {
        // definition of an engine
    };

    Engine.prototype.constructor = Engine;
    Engine.prototype.start = function() {
        console.log('start engine');
    };

    /**
     * Tank
     * @constructor
     * @returns {Tank}
     */
    var Tank = function() {
        // definition of a tank
    };

    Tank.prototype.constructor = Tank;
    Tank.prototype.fill = function() {
        console.log('fill tank');
    };

    this.engine = new Engine();
    this.tank = new Tank();
};

BobsGarage.Car.prototype.constructor = BobsGarage.Car;

/**
 * BobsGarage.Ferrari
 * Derived from BobsGarage.Car
 * @constructor
 * @returns {BobsGarage.Ferrari}
 */
BobsGarage.Ferrari = function() {
    BobsGarage.Car.call(this);
};
BobsGarage.Ferrari.prototype = Object.create(BobsGarage.Car.prototype);
BobsGarage.Ferrari.prototype.constructor = BobsGarage.Ferrari;
BobsGarage.Ferrari.prototype.speedUp = function() {
    console.log('speed up');
};

// Test it on the road

var car = new BobsGarage.Car();
car.tank.fill();
car.engine.start();

var ferrari = new BobsGarage.Ferrari();
ferrari.tank.fill();
ferrari.engine.start();
ferrari.speedUp();

// var engine = new Engine(); // ReferenceError

console.log(ferrari);
```

This way you can have *prototype inheritance* and *nested classes* so that classes defined within `BobsGarage.Car` are not accessible outside the constructor of `BobsGarage.Car` but instances of them are accessible to derived classes, as shown in the test code.

Note: I am referring to the concept of *Class* in Javascript as defined on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript).

Answer (score 7):

use this.myObjB instead of var myObjB

Answer (score 3):

[Object literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178904/simple-javascript-question-what-is-this-thing#178916):

```
var objA = {
    myObjB: {
       testPrint: function(){
          print("Inside test print");
       }
    }
};

objA.myObjB.testPrint();
```

Comment: Who voted this down?  This is a perfectly valid answer, missing only "objA.myObjB.testPrint()"!

Comment: When we refer to "this" inside the testPrint method, are we referring to myObjB or objA?

Comment: To answer my previous question - it's objA, so this doesn't seem like a good implementation of namespaces.

Comment: this isn't using classes, objA and myObjB are both just objects

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do inheritance then you may want to consider the **prototype** keyword.

```
var myObjB = function(){
    this.testPrint = function () {
       print ( " Inside testPrint " );
    }
}

var myObjA = new myObjB();
myObjA.prototype = {
   var1 : "hello world",
   test : function(){
      this.testPrint(this.var1);
   }
}
```

(i hope that made sense)

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of TestA does not expose any public members.
To expose myObjB, you need to make it public:

```
function TestA() {
    this.myObjB = new TestB();
}
var objA = new TestA();
var objB = objA.myObjB;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is another way to do that.

```js
class A {
  constructor(classB) {
    this.ObjB = classB
  }
}

class B {
  Hello() {
    console.log("Hello from class B")
  }
}

let objA = new A(new B())

objA.ObjB.Hello()
```