# Can we add nested objects directly inside a class? What would be the correct syntax?

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, nested

I'm getting into web development and started learning JavaScript a few days ago. In this code I'm trying to create a 'player' class that has abilities (including cannonball). Abilities would be a nested object inside the player class. Cannonball would be a nested object of the abilities object. When I try to create a player I get an error with the syntax of 'abilities: {' Sorry if I'm totally butchering the title of everything. I'm only a few days into coding in general!

```
class player {
  constructor(name,phrase) {
    this._name = name;
    this._catchPhrase = phrase;
  }
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
  abilities: {
    cannonball: {
      damage: 20;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe, instead of calling this a nested object, would this be a nested class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your abilities property work as shown below. See comments in the code for details.
(And refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) early and often for all your web-related ponderings.)

```js
class Player { // Uses initial capital letter by convention

  constructor(name, phrase) {
    this._name = name;
    this._catchPhrase = phrase;

    // Adds the `abilities` property to all instances of Player
    this.abilities = {
      // abilities is an object with a cannonball property
      cannonball: {
        // cannonball is an object with a damage property
        damage: 20 // No semicolon in object literal
      }
    };
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
}
// Makes a new player, and shows that her abilities include `cannonball`
const player = new Player("Grandma", "Hold my beer!");
for(let prop of Object.keys(player.abilities)){  
  console.log(player.abilities[prop]);
}
```

Comment: Hey cat! Thank you so much for your input! In case you're interested here's the final simple project I setup for myself. (currently on day 4 of learning JavaScript), I'm sure there's better ways to write this little program... but it's the best I got (for now!...) Also, I'm new to stackoverflow, my apologies if formatting on this is awkward too lol

Answer (score 1):

Javascript do not have the syntax like `class player { abilities: {...} }`.

[More information about javascript classes.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

You can bind your `abilities` object to player instance on construtor, or use `getter` instead.

```
// example
class player {
    constructor(name, phrase) {
        this._name = name;
        this._catchPhrase = phrase;
        // your abilities object
        this.abilities = {
            cannonball: {
                damage: 20;
            }
        }
    }

    // or use getter
    get abilities() {
        return {
            cannonball: {
                damage: 20;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you really need a **nested-class** solution like Java, see Lorenzo Polidori's answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185680/javascript-nested-class).

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I found this syntax to work! If possible could someone critique this? Basically this class should hold name, catchphrase, two abilities (different objects that contain damage and currAmount)!

Thank you all!

```
class player {
  constructor(name,phrase) {
    this._name = name;
    this._catchPhrase = phrase;
    this._abilities = {
      _cannonball: {
        _damage: 20,
        _currAmount: 3,
      },
      _arrows: {
        _damage: 10,
        _currAmount: 10,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final mini project I was asking this question for. I'm currently on day 4 of learning Javascript and this is the best I got. Thank you so much again!

```
class player {
  constructor(name,phrase) {
    this._name = name;
    this._catchPhrase = phrase;
    this._health = 100;
    this._abilities = {
        _cannonball: {
          _damage: 20,
          _currAmount: 3,
        },
        _arrows: {
          _damage: 10,
          _currAmount: 10,
        },
    }
  }
  set lowerCannon(lowerBy) {
    this._abilities._cannonball._currAmount -= lowerBy;
  }
  set lowerArrows(lowerBy) {
    this._abilities._arrows._currAmount -= lowerBy;
  }
  set lowerHealth(lowerBy) {
    this._health -= lowerBy;
    if (this._health <= 0) {
      this._health = 0;
    }
  }
}

//shooting functions that lower current amount
var shootCannon = (playerTurn,playerHit) => {
  if (playerTurn._health === 0 || playerHit._health === 0)
  {
    //console.log('Game has already ended!')
  }
  if (playerTurn._abilities._cannonball._currAmount === 0) {
    console.log(`${playerTurn._name} is out of Cannonballs!`)
    shootArrows(playerTurn,playerHit);
  }
  else {
  playerTurn.lowerCannon = '1';
  playerHit.lowerHealth = playerTurn._abilities._cannonball._damage;
  console.log(`${playerTurn._name} has fired a cannonball dealing ${playerTurn._abilities._cannonball._damage} damage!...`);
  console.log()
  console.log(`${playerHit._name}'s health is now at ${playerHit._health}!`);
  console.log()
  }
}
var shootArrows = (playerTurn,playerHit) => {
  if (playerTurn._health === 0 || playerHit._health === 0)
  {
    //console.log('Game has already ended!')
  }
    if (playerTurn._abilities._arrows._currAmount === 0) {
    console.log(`${playerTurn._name} is out of arrows!`)
    shootCannonball(playerTurn,playerHit);
  }
  else {
  playerTurn.lowerArrows = '1';
  playerHit.lowerHealth = playerTurn._abilities._arrows._damage;
  console.log(`${playerTurn._name} has fired arrows! dealing ${playerTurn._abilities._arrows._damage} damage!...`);
  console.log()
  console.log(`${playerHit._name}'s health is now at ${playerHit._health}!`);
  console.log()
  }
}

//Make computer fight each other functions
var randomAttack = (playerTurn,playerHit) =>{
  index = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
  if (index === 1) {
    return shootArrows(playerTurn,playerHit);
  }
  else {
    return shootCannon(playerTurn,playerHit);
  }
}
var botMatch = (playerTurn,playerHit) => {
  if (playerTurn._health <= 0 || playerHit._health <= 0) {
    if (playerTurn._health > playerHit._health) {
      console.log(`${playerTurn._name} has won!`)
    }
    if (playerTurn._health < playerHit._health) {
      console.log(`${playerHit._name} has won!`)
    }
    console.log('Game Over!')
  }
  else {
    randomAttack(playerTurn,playerHit);
    randomAttack(playerHit,playerTurn);
    botMatch(playerTurn,playerHit);
  }
}

const player1 = new player('Juan','Let\'s Go!');
const player2 = new player('Jaileth','Beep Beep');

botMatch(player1,player2);
```